# Probleme shortcode with list author

Tags: functions, shortcode, page-template, list-authors

I have created a list of my contributors for my website it works well. I'm trying to do this with a shortcode in my functions.php. The list appears well. But when I want to place it in my theme in any page, it appears before the content whereas I want it to be at the bottom of the page of its appropriate page template. I can't seem to find my mistake

```php
    function comite_shortcode( $atts ){
        $contributor_member = array(
             'role'    => 'Contributor',
             'orderby' => 'user_nicename',
             'order'   => 'ASC',
             'number'  => 2,
        );
        $authors = get_users($contributor_member);
            foreach ($authors as $users):
                echo '<div class="column-member">';
                    echo '<div class="info-member">';
                        echo '<span class="comite-description-name">'.$users->display_name.'</span>';
                        echo '<span class="comite-description">'.$users->institution_rattachementUser.'</span>';
                        echo '<span class="comite-description">'.$users->fonctionUser.'</span>';
                        echo '<span class="comite-description">'.$users->responsableUser.'</span>';
                    echo'</div>';       
                echo'</div>';           
                 echo'<hr class="separator-member">';
            endforeach;
            $html = ob_get_contents();
            return $html; // On renvoie le contenu }
add_shortcode( 'comite', 'comite_shortcode' );
```

Comment: I noticed you called `ob_get_contents` to close your output buffer but where did you start it? I can't find an `ob_start` call in your shortcodes function

Comment: Ah exactly thank, it works better now. But I don't understand why it appears in two places on the page. at the bottom of the page (normal position) and at the top of the page (not normal). Where could it come from?

Comment: because without `ob_start` it's outputting directly to the browser, which is broken behaviour. But it appears `ob_get_contents` still works despite this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because output buffers are closed, but they're never opened.

Adding this at the beginning of the shortcode will fix things:

```php
ob_start();
```

Comment: It works thanks, there was another problem. I had to put  `$html = ob_get_clean();` and delete `ob_end_flush();`